# What is this question asking for exactly?

Tags: geometry

So I'm given a question that asks:

"A coffee filter is cone shaped with radius = 4 and height of 8. Suppose filter is filled with water up to a height of level h. Find an expression for the volume of water in the filter in terms of h (recall the volume of cone is $\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h$). Hint: look for similar figures and make a proportion"

at first glance I'm thinking I just have to rewrite the volume formula for h but the hint makes it seem like it's not that simple.

Comment: Maybe what they're getting at is that you need to consider similar triangles to write $r$ in terms of $h$?

Comment: Just find an expression, $r(h)$ and plug into the volume formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the image representing your situation: [image]

By similar triangles it follows that

$$ \frac{4}{r}=\frac{8}{h}~\Leftrightarrow4h = 8r \Leftrightarrow r = \frac{h}{2} $$

As the volume of the cone is $V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$

Plugging the radius in terms of height in we get

$$ V = \frac{\pi h^3}{12}$$

Answer (score 3):

You are expected to find a relationship between $r$ and $h$, then plug that into the volume formula $V=\frac 13\pi r^2h$ to get a formula for $V$ that only depends on $h$, not on $r$